# Find variable "x" in window where x = 1150?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

In the Chrome Dev JS Console, I know there is variable in window (window.hasOwnProperty) that contains the value 1150. I want to find the variable in window where the variable = 1150. I wrote up this:

```
function getDatVar(par1) {
    for(var xyz in window) {
        if(window.hasOwnProperty(xyz) && window[xyz] == par1) console.log(xyz);
    }
}

getDatVar(1150);
```

However, this just returns `undefined`. How would I find the variable?

Comment: You should be seeing the name of your variable followed by `undefined`. Can you take a screenshot of your console?

Comment: @Hydrothermal http://imgur.com/a/O5Mzh

Comment: Your code works fine for me. How sure are you that the variable you're looking for actually exists?

Comment: I am positive. Just logging all the variables in window works. But I can't find the variable with that data.

Answer (score 0):

That code doesn't have a return statement, just shows the property (xyz) on the console.

You should add a return inside the if so it returns the property.

Comment: I know that, I don't want to return anything, I want it displayed to the console. But I get `undefined`

Comment: Same than @Hydrothermal, code works. Could you give us some information about the property you're looking for?, the moment in which it is set, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching through `window` variables, but the variable that contained that data was in another object. I would need a script that searches through EVERYTHING. Which would be taxing on the browser.